# Laracasts Presenter on a Paginated Instance

Tags: laravel, pagination

My presenter works perfectly until I make it a paginator instance. I realize it's not a model object anymore so present() can not be called. Is there a workaround on this so you can still use your presenter on a paginated instance?

Here is my code:
In my controller I have this:

```
$topics = $this->topic->getPaginatedTopics( $id );
```

In my topics repo, I have this:

```
/*************************
 * QUERIES *
*************************/
/**
 * Get topics under category
 * @param id       Category ID
 *
 * @return Eloquent Object
 */
public function getByCategory( $id )
{
        if( ! $this->cache->has( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ) ) )
    {
        $data = $this->getCategoryWithTopics( $id );

        return $this->cache->getRemember( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ), $data->topics, 20 );
    }

    return $this->cache->get( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ) );
}

/**
 * Get paginated topics
 * @param id       Category ID
 *
 * @return Exemplary Object
 */
public function getPaginatedTopics( $id )
{
    $topics = $this->getByCategory( $id );

    return $this->paginator->make( $topics->toArray(), count($topics), $this->topicsPerPage );
}
```

This returns an Eloquent collection. I have caching involved so I don't call paginate( 20 ) within my query. I make it manually after I pull the cached collection. When I was returning just the Collection, the presenter worked fine. However, I didn't want to cache each paginated page manually because I append a new record with every new topic created so I don't have to clear and re-cache to save that processing on my server.

I can do a getCollection() on the paginator instance, but this just returns a general collection, not a forumtopic collection (the model), so it doesn't know which presenter is attached to the collection.

When I do a dd(), I get a paginator object: object(Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator)[606] When I turn it into an array by ->toArray(), I get this:

```
array (size=7)
  'total' => int 7
  'per_page' => int 25
  'current_page' => int 1
  'last_page' => int 1
  'from' => int 1
  'to' => int 7
  'data' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 65
          'title' => string 'This should append to the top' (length=29)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:53:55' (length=19)
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 64
          'title' => string 'Appendage should work' (length=21)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:51:42' (length=19)
      2 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 63
          'title' => string 'COME ON!' (length=8)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:36:12' (length=19)
      3 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 51
          'title' => string 'This would should work like a charm!' (length=36)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:26:28' (length=19)
      4 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 50
          'title' => string 'Testing cache clear' (length=19)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:20:36' (length=19)
      5 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 46
          'title' => string 'Appending to cache?' (length=19)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 21:17:49' (length=19)
      6 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 33
          'title' => string 'Testing presenter' (length=17)
          'category_id' => int 1
          'user_id' => int 3
          'sticky' => int 0
          'locked' => int 0
          'created_at' => string '2015-03-06 19:06:48' (length=19)
```

Just to show you what I get. Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I may have figured it out :) My code now looks like this. In my controller, I have:

```
$this->topic->getPaginatedTopics( $id, $this->input->get('page') );
```

In my repo, I now have:

```
/*************************
 * QUERIES *
*************************/
/**
 * Get topics under category
 * @param id       Category ID
 *
 * @return Eloquent Object
 */
public function getByCategory( $id )
{
        if( ! $this->cache->has( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ) ) )
    {
        $data = $this->getCategoryWithTopics( $id );

        return $this->cache->getRemember( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ), $data->topics, 20 );
    }

    return $this->cache->get( $this->getTopicCacheName( $id ) );
}

/**
 * Get paginated topics
 * @param id       Category ID
 *
 * @return Exemplary Object
 */
public function getPaginatedTopics( $id, $page = 1 )
{
    $topics = $this->getByCategory( $id )->sortByDesc(function($topic)
    {
        return $topic->created_at;
    });

    $offset = (($page - 1) * $this->topicsPerPage);

    return $this->paginator->make(
        $topics->slice($offset, $this->topicsPerPage, true)->all(),
        $topics->count(),
        $this->topicsPerPage
    );
}
```

Then your view looks like it would originally where you iterate through your records and can call their attributes like $topic->title and such and your presenter still works as it should :) And your caching stays as it should. Hopefully this helps other people!